# Install brand new android API on my old Jelly Bean phone?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

Hello Android enthusiasts,

I'd like to know one thing :

I have a Jelly Bean phone. Which is API 16. What if I use Android SDK API 26 in Android Studio to create an app that uses classes of API 26... Can I use this app on my Jelly Bean phone ?

If not, how can I install API 26 in my Jelly Bean phone (if at all possible) ? (any option here I will take...)

Answer (score 0):

u can do that only by installing oreo(api 26) based custom rom in your phone and it depends upon ur mobile model and year of manufacture if your is too old its very unlikely to get oreo based custom rom. Best option is using Emulators

Comment: Phone is ALCATEL MPOP 5020D... Wow I'll be lucky if I can find a custom Oreo ROM for it... Also, emulator is not an option since I need to perform GSM operations...

Comment: What type of gsm operations